# Как отправить запрос методом execute в библиотеке vk_api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я хочу пометить прочитанными диалог, используя метод `execute`:

```
await event.api_ctx.execute(code = 'return API.message.markAsRead({"peer_id":chat});')
```

Но мне выдает ошибку:

```
[12] Unable to compile code:  undefined identifier 'chat' in line 1
```

Как же тогда указывать значение аргумента `peer_id`, если оно хранится в переменной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
await event.api_ctx.execute(
code="return API.message.markAsRead({\"peer_id\":" + str(chat) + "});"
)
```